# Bad Request received in trying to get Flask form to display

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Flask form that takes the username but it doesn't work. I keep getting a `Bad Request` error. Here's my code:

This is my `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    variable = request.form["recipe"]
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__=='__main__': 
    app.run()
```

This is my `index.html` that the form resides in:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Cooking By Myself</h1>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <h3>Add Recipe</h3>
        <p>
            <label for="recipe">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="recipe"/>
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit_recipe"/></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my `base.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code lies in the index function(main.py) of your Flask application. You're trying to access the `request.form` attribute without checking if the request method is a POST request. This causes a Bad Request error when the page is initially loaded because the form data is not available in the `request.form` dictionary initially.

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        recipe = request.form.get("recipe")
        # Process the recipe data as needed
        print(f"Recipe: {recipe}")
    return render_template("index.html")
```